# Instagram webpage auto opens when navigated to abous us menu

Tags: java, android, android-studio

my app is running into this problem of auto opening a webpage to instagram when I navigate to the about us menu. I only want this to happen once the user has clicked on the instagram text so it presents the option of opening instagram with the insta app or in a webpage
any idea on how to fix this problem?

**aboutactivity that has the intents to send the user to corresponding apps**

```
package com.example.vitoriano_vaz.eastbayvapes;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AboutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

        Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:9259519029");
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);

        Uri webpage = Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/eastbay");
        Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);

        // intent to send user to instagram
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/_u/eastbay");
        final Intent likeIng = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

        likeIng.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

        try {
            startActivity(likeIng);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/eastbay")));
        }


        TextView instaText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        instaText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    startActivity(likeIng);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/eastbay")));
                }
            }
        });


        //Intent to send user to email app

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("plain/text");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"eastbay@gmail.com"});
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));

    }
}
```

Comment: well you are running startactivity right in oncreate which runs when the activity is open. you need to put in a button click listener
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-button-example/

Comment: @Tomer Shemesh so in my xml should i give the instagram text a button? with the other business info i dont have this issue.

Comment: no you dont need to make it a button you just need to make an on click. hold on ill post an answer with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make the activity launch inside an onclick listener not inside you activity main. you will need to do the same thing for your mail intent which is also in your oncreate.

```
package com.example.vitoriano_vaz.eastbayvapes;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AboutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);


        Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:9259619029");
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);

        Uri webpage = Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/eastbayvapes");
        Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);

        // intent to send user to instagram

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/_u/eastbayvapes");
        Intent likeIng = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

        likeIng.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

        TextView instaText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_TEXTVIEW_ID);
        instaText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                startActivity(likeIng);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/eastbayvapes")));
            }
        }
    });


        //Intent to send user to email app
      TextView emailText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_TEXTVIEW_ID);
        emailText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("plain/text");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"eastbayvapes@gmail.com"});
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));
        }
    });


    }
}
```

Comment: so i attempted your method and i am still getting the same result of the instgram webpage auto opening when navigated to the aboutus menu trying your code and making an onClick in my xml

Comment: So this should not be in the onCreate?

Comment: you forgot to remove the preexisting code from oncreate see my example

Comment: Thank you the problem was solved and you made me realize i will have to do the same with my email intent because it is giving the same problem